# How do I use console.log to check my code?

Tags: jquery, logging, firebug

I have been told that this is a useful means of checking code but how do I actually use it? Do I type it from within firebug or onto my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use

```
console.log(<object>)
```

in your code.  Where  is something you want to log.

As the other poster references.  [Firebug Logging Documentation](http://getfirebug.com/logging) is helpful

The Chrome debugger works the same way with console.log() IE does not.

Also note you should not leave console.log in your code as run-time code will fail if you leave that in and you don't have a console object.

Comment: IE also has console.log as of IE 8; you have to have the console open ahead of time, of course.

Comment: To expand on my previous thought, the example given here would create an error if the debug console is not already open.

Answer (score 0):

Put `console.log("text");` in the JS code whenever you want to print. Then, click on console in firebug to view the text.

Answer (score 0):

As of IE 8, all the browsers now have a console (which you can open with F12). You can also get [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) for any non-FF browser.

None of the answers so far have pointed out that putting console.log into your code will create an error in IE if the console is not open.

Here is how I handle my console.log calls:

```
function logIt() {
   if( !console || !console.log ) { return; }
   for(i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      console.log(arguments[i]);
   }
}
```

Naturally, in my code, I just call `logIt` with whatever variables or text I want to analyze:

```
logIt("Here is the array", arrayOfWidgets);
```

Or, if you think you might be using this logging frequently, you can improve performance considerably with the following scoping changes (note that you have to send the arguments in reverse order as they will be dispayed ;)

```
function logIt() {
   var i = arguments.length, log = console? console.log : null;
   if( !log ) { return; }
   while(i--) {
      log(arguments[i]);
   }
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
logIt(arrayOfWidgets, "Here is the array");
```